# Нужен ли дефис?

Tags: орфография

...фиолетовый сочетается с **нежно-светящимся** желтым, создавая контраст на веках.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, не нужен: фиолетовый сочетается с ( каким?)светящимся (как?)нежно-причастный оборот-причастие с зависимым наречием.Это не оттенок цвета.